# continue doing something IN the usual schedule

Tags: sentence-construction

I came up with the following sentence:

> It sometimes happens that I forget about weekends and holiday and
>    continue working **in** the usual schedule but on my own projects.

Does it sound natural? I'm not sure about the preposition *in*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal preposition is you [work **to** a schedule](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22work+to+a+schedule%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (BrE, but see <sup><sub>1</sub></sup> below for AmE).

There's often no easy way to predict what preposition to use in any given context, but I'd classify this one alongside other ***verb + preposition + [constraint]*** usages such as...

> ***cook to order*** - only cook meals that have been ordered
>    ***work to rule*** - only perform work as specified by the rules
>    ***season to taste*** - only add seasoning that suits your taste

If it helps, you could understand this type of preposition usage as meaning ***according*** to.

---

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> See comments below, acknowledging that Americans are more likely to *work **on** a schedule*

Comment: Cisatlantically we tend to work **on** a schedule. (Actually most  of us tend to work *behind* schedule, but you know what I mean.)

Comment: @StoneyB: Ah, right! I was aware of that as an "also-ran", but I didn't realise it's actually [the more common usage in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+on+a+schedule%2Cwork+to+a+schedule&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20on%20a%20schedule%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20to%20a%20schedule%3B%2Cc0). I didn't want to mention it partly because from *my* perspective it's not very common - but mainly because it screwed up my attempt to identify a "pattern". But you've forced the issue, so I'll flag it up in the answer! :)

Comment: We can also say: "I am working my usual schedule" without any preposition.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't know, tell me, please.

Comment: @DmitryBundin It's a joke. To be behind schedule is to have failed to finished things when you were supposed.

Comment: @Dmitry: In AmE the preposition is likely to be ***on*** rather than BrE ***to*** for your exact context, but only the most extreme pedant on *either* side of the Atlantic would say the alternative was "wrong". Note that *all* native speakers normally use *We are **on** schedule* to mean *meeting planned completion dates* (as opposed to ***behind, ahead of*** for being late, or completing the work earlier than planned).

Comment: ...in my experience, AmE tends to use less *different* prepositions in different contexts. As in this case, where BrE tends to use *work **to** [a] schedule* to mean there actually *is* a schedule "controlling" the work, where *to be **on** schedule* specifically means progress so far ***is meeting*** planned dates (the job is expected to be complete ***on time***).